# how to calculate this using substitution?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I have hard times calculating this integral: ($a>0$)
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{u} \, du = \sqrt{u^2-a^2}-a\arccos \left(\frac a {|u|}\right)+C$$
My effort is putting $u=a\sec(t)$ and then I get lost! Actually I make some progress but I dont know what to do with $\arccos(u/|a|).$

Note1: I asked this question for answers from putting $u=a\sec(t).$

Note2: I described my efforts in this link. In the question asked here I want the solution from scratch, but in the question in the link I want to know my errors.
[2 subtle problems on calculating this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503195/2-subtle-problems-on-calculating-this-integral)

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
u & = a\left| \sec t \right| = \pm a\sec t \text{ according as } \pm u\ge0. \\
du & = \pm a\sec t \tan t
\end{align}
$$ Thus you have $\text{“}{+}\text{''}$ when $u\ge0$ and $\text{“}{-}\text{''}$ when $u \le 0. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the use of $u=a\sec t $ is required, you need to be specific about its domain and range. Let $t\in [0,\frac\pi2)$, then the range of $u$ is $(a,\infty)$. So, to integrate 
$$I=\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{u} \, du $$

where $u<-a$ and $u>a$, two cases need to be considered separately.

Case 1): $u>a$. With $u=a\sec t $, we have $\tan t = \sqrt{u^2-a^2}$, $\cos t = \frac au$, and

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{u} du = a\int \tan^2 t\>dt = a \tan t - at =\sqrt{u^2-a^2}-a\cos^{-1}\frac au$$

Case 2): $u<-a$. Use $u=-a\sec t $. Then,  $\tan t = \sqrt{u^2-a^2}$, $\cos t = -\frac au = \frac a{|u|}$, and

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{u} du = a\int \tan^2 t\>dt = a \tan t - at =\sqrt{u^2-a^2}-a\cos^{-1}\frac a{|u|}$$
Now, combine the two results as one to cover both $u<-a$ and $u>a$,

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{u} du  =\sqrt{u^2-a^2}-a\cos^{-1}\frac a{|u|}+C$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503195/2-subtle-problems-on-calculating-this-integral        please help me in this too. My solution is very much like yours. a comment or answer would be appreciated in that link.

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh - I answered your other post.